# Let's give the partial derivatives , where is $f'_{x}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y):=$\begin{cases}
      \frac{x^2-xy}{x+y}, & \text{if}\ x\ne -y \\
      0, & \text{if} (x,y)=(0,0)
    \end{cases}

Comment: What about $x=-y\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

At any point not in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ or the line $y=-x$ you have 
$$
f'_x(x,y) = \frac{(2x-y)(x+y) - (x^2-xy)}{(x+y)^2} = \frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+y)^2}=1.
$$
At $N_{\delta}((0,0))$ the function is not elementary function, then
$$
f'_x(x,y) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{ \frac{(\Delta x) ^2}{\Delta x} - 0 } {\Delta x} = 1.
$$
Hence, because the domain of $f'x$ is a subset $\subseteq$ of the domain of $f$, then $f'x(x,y)=1$  - constant, and thus continuous - over $D_f$.